# WPF -- Automatic CRUD Builder?

Tags: wpf, crud

Are there any WPF CRUD builders out there yet?

Answer (score 4):

Here ya go: [WPF CRUD Generator (Scaffolding)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/crudgenerator.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this control [WPFCrudControl](https://github.com/GenericCodes/WPFCrudControl).

A generic WPF CrudControl implemented based on the MVVM pattern. It gives a huge productivity boost for straightforward CRUD operations (Add, Edit, Delete, Validate, Listing with sorting, paging and searching). The control abstracts both the UI and business logic, so it requires relatively minimal coding effort, while keeping it possible to customize its behavior.